# Is $f(x)=e^x$ the only solution to $f(f'(x))=f'(f(x))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

> Is $f(x)=e^x$ the only solution to $f(f'(x))=f'(f(x))$?

In particular I'm interested in the qualitative properties of the such solutions.

Comment: Well, $f(x)=0$ is a solution. As is $f(x)=x$.

Comment: $f'(f(x))$ means $f' o f(x)$?

Comment: And in the same way as Thomas suggests, the functions $f(x)=ax^n$, $n\in\mathbf N$ works, one just has to choose specific values of $a$. For exaple, for $n=2$, $a=1/2$ will do. (For general $n$ it seems that $a=1/n^{n-1}$ works, unless I did some stupid mistake.)

Comment: Also $f(x) = k e^x $ for any constant $k$ ...  $f = f'$ so they must commute.

Comment: @user26857 Would you say this is a badly asked question?

Comment: @user26857 I added something to the question details. What are the qualitative properties of the solutions to such a differential equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the comments there are plenty of real-valued functions satisfying your equation. Here are the examples found so far (posting this as CW so that the question has an answer):

1. $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = x$ (Thomas Andrews)
2. $f(x) = n\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{R}_+\text{\\}\{0\}$ (mickep)
3. $f(x) = ke^{x}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{R}$ (Ned)
4. $f(x) = a(x+1-a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It was a question, not a conjecture.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: @BrianTung Because I initially wrote "your conjecture is not correct". I corrected it, but it's Community Wiki so it does not matter anyway.

Comment: I saw that.  That seemed like a good reason for the comment; I wondered about the downvote.  The answer seems solid, one way or the other.

Comment: 1. is special case of 4. (with $a=0$ and $a=1$)